# move_uploaded_file() is not working in Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, file-upload

> I am working on wordpess with PHP code but uploaded file is not moving in upload folder with move_uploaded_file() also it is not showing me any error

```html
<form action="" id="review_form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
 <input type="file" name="yourfile" class="wp-form-control wp-file" aria-invalid="false">
</form>
```

```
$path =  "https://test.com/wp-content/themes/test/review_upload/";
$my_file =  basename($_FILES['yourfile']['name']);
$path1 = $path . $my_file;
$move = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['yourfile']['tmp_name'], $path1);
```

Comment: Looks like you tried to move the file to an URL address

Comment: Yes, I have tried to move file to URL address

Comment: I see, actually it only working if you use local path like `C:/folder/file.txt` or `./folder/file.txt`.. maybe you should check the example on the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)

Comment: So, what if I want to work with live path?

Comment: You should have a significantly better reason than "I want to". Be more effortful in describing why you're not using the filesystem path.

Answer (score 1):

You should use local file System path that specify the target for move_uploaded_file instead of the url, please try this below code.

```
$DirPath    =  wp_dir_path.'/uploads/2014/foldername/';
```

Comment: when i use this code it gives me - (Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error))

Comment: check the path of the variable if its return the path correct or not? and you are in ubuntu please go ahead and give permission to the folder.

Comment: I have check all path are correct and I am using windows so there is no permission issue